# MIPS32 aluipc instruction implemented in java

Tags: java, mips32

I'm implementing MIPS32 instruction set in Java to build a simulator. I have come to the aluipc instruction and I'm unsure whether what I'm doing is correct of not.

In the docs for MIPS 32 it say "This instruction performs a PC-relative address calculation. The 16-bit immediate is shifted left by 16 bits, signextended,
and added to the address of the ALUIPC instruction. The low 16 bits of the result are cleared, that is the
result is aligned on a 64K boundary. The result is placed in GPR rs."

and the operation example they give is :

```
    GPR[rs] <- ~0x0FFFF & ( PC + sign_extend( immediate << 16 ) )
```

My code is:

```
    0x0FFFF & (v1 + (v2 << 16));
```

Where v1 is the pc and v2 is the immediate, am i correct in thinking that i simple store this in an int and thats the answer? or do i clear the 16 lower bits and only store the high 16?

Comment: Did you forget the tilde?

Comment: @drhr yes i did with that added i think its giving the correct answer by my understanding thank you